# Software Updater gives "Failed to download repository information - Public key is not available" Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: updates, 17.10

When i RUn Software Updater I get error.

So Tried to go to "Other Software" and only check Canonical Partners, then I get this error :

> Failed to download repository information
>
> W:GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com precise Release: The
>   following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is
>   not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5, E:The repository
>   'http://archive.canonical.com precise Release' is not signed.

I have tried:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 40976EAF437D05B5
[sudo] password for sindre: 
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.gl6NzrufIJ/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 40976EAF437D05B5
```

But it did not help. Looks like it never gets executed because it gets time out. (gpg: keyserver receive failed: Connection timed out).

Print of sources.list

```
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful main restricted
# deb-src http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful universe
# deb-src http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates universe
# deb-src http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful multiverse
# deb-src http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu artful partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu artful partner

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ precise partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ precise partner
```

Comment: @karel I tried the fix in that thread, it did not help.

Comment: There is a link in your software sources to an obsolete source from Ubuntu 12.04 precise which is no longer supported. Deleting that line in `/etc/apt/sources.list` will fix the error in your question. [Can I mix sources from different ubuntu versions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/499800/can-i-mix-sources-from-different-ubuntu-versions)

Comment: @karel I dont know what line I am going to delete. I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 17.10 (no upgrade). I added the print out of sources.list to my question.

Comment: Put a hash character **#** in front of the second to last line in sources.list - `deb http://archive.canonical.com/ precise partner` to turn that line into a comment.

Comment: @karel It worked. Nice. But Firefox did not update, I still got v 56. Is this related to you think?

Comment: It's not related. Firefox 57 update has not been released yet.

Comment: @karel I got the new Firefox 57 today!

Comment: I updated my Firefox to 57 and not all of my old Firefox extensions are supported in Firefox 57, so I learned how to do the same thing without installing an extension in Firefox 57. I posted what I did as an answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/516033/how-to-have-websites-fit-the-screen/976958#976958).

Answer (score 0):

I edited  /etc/apt/sources.list

Then added # in front of the second to last line in sources.list

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ precise partner

Now I can fetch updates.